# $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\beta^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$ does not exist.

Tags: field-theory

I'm stuck on proving that.

Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible cubic polynomial which has three real roots, and $f(\alpha)=0$,
then there does not exist $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\beta^3 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I'll write down what I noticed.

- $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ is base of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$
- Let $g$ is minimal polynomial of $\beta$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathrm{deg}(g) = 3$.
- Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ are roots of $f$ ($\alpha$ is one of them), then $xyz, x+y+z, xy+xz+yz \in \mathbb{Q}$

please some hint or solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the question asking to show that there exists such a $\beta$?

Comment: @Bonnaduck I want to show that there does not exists such a $\beta$.

Comment: @Bonnaduck Yes! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose there exists such a $\beta$. It is clear that $\beta \not \in \Bbb Q$.

Then there is an embedding $\Bbb Q(\beta) \hookrightarrow \Bbb C$ which maps $\beta$ to a non-real complex number, because the three roots of $X^3 - \beta^3$ are not all real.

However since $f(X)$ has three real roots, any embedding $\Bbb Q(\alpha) \hookrightarrow\Bbb C$ would have image contained in $\Bbb R$. This contradicts $\Bbb Q(\alpha) = \Bbb Q(\beta)$.

Comment: Sorry, why it can be conclude that if the roots of $X^3-\beta$ are not all real, then $\beta$ maps to a complex number?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It should be $X^3 - \beta^3$. The quotient of two different roots is a third root of unity, which is non-real.

Comment: I think the roots of $X^3-\beta^3$ are $\beta, \beta\omega, \beta\omega^2$ and at least one of them is a complex number.
But, I cannot conclude $\beta$ maps to a non-real complex number by this.
I'm sorry again and again.

Comment: @Calico The point (or at least one of the ways of looking at it) is that there is a non-real subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\beta\omega)$ of $\Bbb{C}$ that is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(\beta)$. But all the subfields of $\Bbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ consist of real numbers only. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

How to tell that two irreducible polynomials do not produce isomorphic extensions:

Let $f$, $g$ be irreducible polynomials in $k[x]$ ( of same degree) that produce isomorphic field extensions $k[x]/(f)$, and   $k[x]/(g)$. Then for their [discriminants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) $\Delta(f)$, $\Delta(g)$, we have
$$\frac{\Delta(f)}{\Delta(g)} \in (k^{\times})^2$$

Now, the [discriminant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Discriminant%5B%20x%5E3-%20b%2C%20x%5D) of the polynomial of the polynomial $x^3- b$ is $-27 b^2$, while the discriminant of a polynomial of degree $3$ with all real roots is a positive number.

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's show the statement about discriminants of polynomials. Consider a polynomial $f\in k[x]$ with roots $x_1$, $\ldots$, $x_n$, and $g\in k[x]$ with roots $t(x_1)$, $\ldots$, $t(x_n)$, where $t(x) \in k(x)$ is a rational function. Then the expression in $x_i$
$$\prod_{i<j} \frac{t(x_i)- t(x_j)}{x_i-x_j}$$
is symmetric, so lies in $k$. Therefore, the quotient of the discriminants of $g$ and $f$ is the square of an element from $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. We have $$\beta=p+q\alpha +r\alpha^2$$ for some rationals $p, q, r$. Replacing $\alpha $ in above equation with the other two roots of $f$ we get two real numbers $\beta _1,\beta_2$ and then by the theorem on symmetric polynomials $\beta, \beta_1,\beta_2$ are roots of a cubic polynomial $g(x) \in\mathbb Q[x] $. And since $\beta$ is of degree $3$ over rationals the polynomial $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb {Q} $. Also $\beta^3$ is rational so the above polynomial $g(x) $ must be of the form $ax^3+b$.

But then we reach a contradiction as the polynomial $ax^3+b$ has at least one root which is not real.